# jqgrid mask decimal number cells

Tags: jqgrid

I have inside my jgrid a column which is of type float , I want to mask the column cells when ever the user enters the cell. for exmple , the mask should be 99999.99 (when 9 = any number between 0-9). i want max 5 digits to the left of the point and max of 2 digits to the right of the point - and that it will be posible to enter less then the max.

How can I mask this column to be a decimal number?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 7):

something like

```
formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 2 }
```

this is from [the wiki docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter) or if those predefined ones don't work you can create a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)

Comment: the formatter is not good for me. i found this:  $(elem).addClass('auto').autoNumeric({aSep: ''});$(elem).autoNumeric({aSep: '',mNum: 5,mDec: 2}); inside dataInit , and it's works like i want.thank's.