# How to restrict input to two decimal places?

Tags: jqgrid

> I am using inline gird where user can add and edit row. 
>       I want to restrict user input for text field,
>       where user could not enter number more than two decimal places.
>       Can anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: This [post][1] might help !!! It does to me     


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065260/jqgrid-mask-decimal-number-cells

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
    number : {decimalSeparator:".", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00'},
```

Reference [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Apredefined_formatter)